# Is it necessary to close Scanner inside Block Lambda Expressions?

Tags: java, lambda, java.util.scanner

I'm new to Lambda Expressions in java and I'm not sure whether is it necessary to additionally close Scanner inside the Block Lambda Expressions:

```
public interface factorialInterface {
    int factorialMe (int n);
    }


import java.util.Scanner;
public class factorialDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner (System.in);

        factorialInterface fact = (n) -> {
            int result = 1;

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                result = i * result;
            }
            keyb.close();  // <- not sure about this one.
            return result;
        };
        System.out.print("Pass value: ");
        System.out.println(fact.factorialMe(keyb.nextInt())); 
        System.out.println();


        keyb.close(); 

    }

}
```

If I won't close 'keyb' inside of this block Eclipse will inform me about the Resource Leak. Is it always recommended to close Scanner inside of the Lambda Block?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you certain you want to close `System.in`?

Comment: I would say eclipse is wrong on this. there is no reason for your lambda to have anything to do with the scanner.

Comment: You should always close a `Scanner`, *except* a `Scanner` on `System.in`. You should never close `System.in`. Eclipse doesn't have that exception, so you have to tell it, by adding `@SuppressWarnings("resource")` on the line right before `Scanner keyb = ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `keyb` inside `fact` in any other way except closing it. It totally does not belong there. Calculation of a factorial of `n` is a pure function that only depends on `n` and nothing else.

This is likely a bug in Eclipse. Try moving the declaration of `keyb` closer to its usage, that is, right after `print("Pass value: ")`.

Comment: Thats exactly my thoughts!  Thanks for the answer. Normally I'd never put the closing statement inside of the block because (as you said) it has nothing to do with the Scanner whatsoever, but since I started reading about Lambda Expressions about an hour ago I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything.